# Сортировка по полю с нулями, идущими последними

Tags: mysql, сортировка

Мне нужно произвести сортировку товаров по возрастанию цены. Делаю так:

```
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Но проблема в том, что сортировка начинается с товаров с ценой `0`, хотя они должны быть в самом конце.
Как реализовать без создания костылей в виде дополнительных полей?

Comment: товары с ценой 0 обязательно отображать?

Comment: да, в конце списка

Comment: Дополнительное поле в SELECT на основе цены=0 и сортировка по друм полям и есть решение а не костыль.

Answer (score 4):

Можно это сделать так:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY price = 0 ASC, price ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

решил так:

```
ORDER BY IF(price > 0,1,0) DESC, price ASC
```